# Need formula for Right in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently working on a spreadsheet which contain dynamic rows (ranges from 1500 to 3000). I need a formula in Column AA4 till the last row which contains the data. I have to use the right formula in AA column which get the data from the Q column.

First row of data is from the 4th row

Currently I am using

```
=Right(Q4,3)
```

Suppose the last row is 1632, the formula becomes `=Right(Q1632,3)`.

Can anyone help me with the VBA for RIGHT formula for the above scenario?

Thanks

Comment: [Find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba), and then `Range("AA4:AA" & lastRow).Formula = "=RIGHT(Q4,3)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that :

```
nb = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AA4:AA" & nb).Formula = "=Right(Q4,3)"
```